# Does the expression "tendency of how" make sense?

Tags: grammar

> In companies A and B, an increase in age by one year yields an increase in
>   a fixed portion of monthly salary by 100 dollars.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above I created by using "tendency". My example is as follows:

> Companies A and B have **the same tendency of how** a fixed portion of monthly salary increases with age.

I think neither are an idiomatic English, but would like to know whether the rewritten sentence is acceptable (understandable).

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would struggle to understand either sentence as intended without more context. I’d also need more context to suggest a better alternative, too.

Comment: Can connecting the first sentence and the second sentence by a conjunction, such as "thus" or "so" make the second understandable?

Comment: I think the problem is semantic rather than simply grammatical. For example, do you mean seniority with the company, time in grade, or employee age when you say “age?” Are you talking about deterministic values, statistics, or percentages related to salary? Word choices can be very dependent on context and intended connotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example sentence could be rephrased as:

> Companies A and B, ***(both)*** **have a tendency** to increase a fixed portion of ***their*** monthly salar***ies*** by 100 dollars for every year increase in age.
>
> For every year increase in age, companies A and B ***(both)*** **have a tendency** to increase a fixed portion of ***their*** monthly salar***ies*** by 100 dollars.

If you really must use tendency, you will need to state what that tendency is immediately after mentioning "***tendency***".

Comment: I used "tendency" because  I can't think of other words. I intended to use the word "tendency" in the second sentence to summarize the first sentence.

Comment: If the "***tendency***" is **strong** (often), you could use **usually** or **often**.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is somewhat puzzling.

It seems that you are trying to say that:

Apart from any other salary increases, employees in Companies A and B will benefit each year from a monthly increase of $100.

In other words, regardless of other increases, they will benefit from a fixed annual increase of $1,200.

I don't see how you are going to work **a tendency** into this sentence. A fixed increase is not a tendency although it might be described as a company policy.

You could be more specific and say that the monthly increase will take effect on the employee's birthday each year, if that is what you intend.

Whether the definite increase is on a **fixed portion** of the salary or not would seem to be irrelevant unless you spell out which portion and why. It might, for example, have tax or pension implications but you would need to say so.